# Maven repo for apache commons beanutils

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, maven

where can i download the dependency Apache commons beanutils
i couldn't find it in many popular repos i am using, please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven Central now has a search website.

http://search.maven.org

Version 1.8.3 of Beanutils is found [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccommons-beanutils%7Ccommons-beanutils%7C1.8.3%7Cjar).

The Maven GAV coordinate to use is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i know the dependency, but what repo should i add to download it from, like: <repository>
            <id>javanet</id>
            <name>Repository for Maven2</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>

Comment: Download from Maven central (The search URL is above). See the answer to the following question. Describes how to enable Maven central in your ivy build: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313316/using-a-custom-repository-with-apache-ivy-no-resolver-found/7362756#7362756

Comment: Oops sorry.... You're a Maven user. Don't worry Maven Central is preconfigured in the Maven client. You don't have to enable anything (Unless you sit behind a network proxy, or your company uses an Enterprise Maven repository)

Answer (score 1):

What GAV are you trying?

Plenty of beanutils in [repo1.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cbeanutils).

Comment: Group, Artifact, Version - http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/ch02s02.html#d4e467. You shouldn't have to add `repo.maven.org` to your settings or you pom as it's there by default. If Maven can't *see* it then maybe you're behind a proxy.

Comment: any ideas how to download it from repo then, or add the dependency manually from eclipse ?

Comment: i was able to download it finally after adding the following repo: <repository>
            <id>Maven Central</id>
            <name>Repository for Maven2</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>