# Ideal repository which is local

Tags: java, maven, ant, build, repository

I'm in the middle of looking into a new repository to be used within my company. We currently use IVY and although this is pretty quickly using our own local repository, the only downside is that we use ANT for build scripts and it's just ugly! I'd like to bring this side of things up to date a little and possibly use something like GRADLE (although I've heard it's slow) but I'm a little lost with the options.

Ideally, I'd like a repository which will be local as we have a number of internal jar files which cannot be shared. If there are dependencies which are available in public repos such as Maven, go off and download them and then even, if it's possible, install them in the local repository.

Any one got any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While ivy can do a fine job hosting a local repository, fact is Maven has become the defacto standard format for storing java artifacts. There are at least 3 well established repository managers that you can run locally:

- [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)
- [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/)
- [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi)

These will provide the following benefits:

1. Locally cache files available from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/)
2. Provide a place to store internal jars that are not available externally.
3. Act as an integration point for different build technologies. Ivy, Maven, Gradle, etc all understand and support Maven repositories.

Ivy supports Maven repositories, see:

- [Using a custom repository with Apache Ivy, no resolver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313316/using-a-custom-repository-with-apache-ivy-no-resolver-found/7362756#7362756)
- [Use public maven repository with ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836011/use-public-maven-repository-with-ivy/4837149#4837149)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about Nexus!